# Retrieving all received messages of a particular user in Firebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

How can I retrieve all received messages of a particular user from Firebase database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
FirebaseDatabase database;
DatabaseReference databaseReference;
database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
databaseReference = database.getReference("firebase_db_name);

DatabaseReference databaseReference = databaseReference.child("your_user");
        databaseReference.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
              if (dataSnapshot != null) {
                  YOUR_OBJECT object =  
                              dataSnapshot.getValue(YOUR_OBJECT.class);
                  // todo in object you will get all your msgs
              }

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
```